# Does Colossus Slayer depends on HP before or after the hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger

> **Colossus Slayer.** Your tenacity can wear down
>   the most potent foes. When you hit a creature with a
>   weapon attack, the creature takes an extra 1d8 damage
>   if it's below its hit point maximum. You can deal this
>   extra damage only once per turn.

For which moment the target must be "below its hit point maximum"? Should I consider its HP before the hit that actually triggers the Colossus Slayer feature? Or can it be the same hit that lowers the target's HP and triggers the feature?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### It depends on HP *before* the hit.

Essentially, an attack can be broken down into a couple phases. First, you select a target. Then you make an attack roll, and determine whether the attack hits or misses (or crits). Then you resolve damage and any other effects (mostly these only happen on a hit).

The damage effectively happens all at once (unless a particular effect explicitly says its damage happens later), so when you're checking whether to add the extra damage for Colossus Slayer, the damage from your hit hasn't been applied yet; Colossus Slayer damage happens at the same time as the rest of the damage for the hit.

The *other* way of thinking about this is that if Colossus Slayer depended on HP *after* the hit, it would pretty much **always** deal its extra damage, unless your hit managed to do zero damage. At which point, they might as well change the feature to read, "You deal an extra 1d8 damage when you hit with an attack." Since the feature *isn't* phrased that way, it seems unlikely that that's how it's intended to work.

Comment: You could also point out that the wording states, "When you *hit* a creature with a weapon attack," not "When you *deal damage* to a creature with a weapon attack.". The feature has no requirement that you deal any initial damage with your hit at all.

Comment: @keithcurtis _extra_ damage depends on the initial damage

Comment: @András The conditional is still *being hit*, not *taking damage*, else the wording would be different. If you have something that reduces part of your damage (even to zero), the you can still take *extra* damage.