# Can you trigger the Ranger's Colossus Slayer with two-weapon-fighting in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, two-weapon-fighting

Colossus Slayer only triggers if you attack a target which doesn't have it's full hit points (meaning they took damage in this fight already).

Would damaging the target with an Attack Action make it possible to then use Colossus Slayer with a bonus action off-hand attack because the opponent doesn't have full hit points anymore?

This would basically mean that a ranger could use Colossus Slayer on nearly every turn except if the Attack Action misses or kills the opponent.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm going to have to ask for clarification. What is the *exact* chain of events you're asking about? The answer might depend on which caveats you have considered and which ones you haven't.

Comment: related https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92732/

Answer (score 23):

**Yes**

It does not matter for Colossus Slayer where the damage had come from and when. The enemy does not have to be missing HP at the start of your turn, but when you deal damage to him. It can certainly come from your own previous attack. Do not forget that you can still only deal the extra damage once a turn.

Comment: You might want to clear up what appears to be a misconception on the part of the OP; Colossus Slayer also permits you to attack twice in the attack action: if the first attack hits and does damage, the *second* can apply bonus damage.  Ie, this principle holds beyond "bonus action" attacks.  (Your answer implies this, but the OP's question seems to indicate a misconception here, and pointing it out explicitly would improve your answer).

Comment: I don't see where Colossus Slayer gives a second attack. You can attack with a bonus action, like any character, and it would deal the additional CS damage if you did damage with your initial attack. But the feature does not grant a second attack in and of itself.

Comment: I think there is confusion with Horde Breaker which is an alternative pick for a ranger to Colossus Slayer which does give the ranger an additional attack in certain conditions. (PHB p.93)

Comment: You can also state that when they get to 5th level, they'll have an extra attack that this can apply to as well.